# How do I compile SCSS into CSS using Webpack & ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

Another ReactJS/Webpack n00b here. I've seen a thousand variations on this question, but what seems to work for others is not working for me.

How do I turn /app/scss/styles.scss into /app/css/styles.css?

Everything appears to compile correctly (no errors) when I run ***npm start***, but I can't locate the compiled styles.css file.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
   template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
   filename: 'index.html',
   inject: 'body'
});
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
   entry: __dirname + '/app/components/index.js',
   module: {
   loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
     },
     {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'compiled.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build'
  },
  plugins: [
    HTMLWebpackPluginConfig,
    new ExtractTextPlugin('/app/css/styles.css')
  ]
};
```

**powershell (command line) output**

```
              Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
        compiled.js  1.06 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
/app/css/styles.css   4.5 kB       0  [emitted]         main
         index.html  10.5 kB          [emitted]
        chunk    {0} compiled.js, /app/css/styles.css (main) 1.03 MB [entry] [rendered]
... yadda yadda ... 
[1] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./app/scss/styles.scss 4.92 kB {0} [built]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

**file structure**

- [NameOfApp]

  - .babelrc
  - package.json
  - webpack.config.js
  - node_modules
  - app

    - index.html
    - scss
    - css (empty)
    - components (js)

Any help is most appreciated. Getting desperate.

Comment: I think by using `/app/css/styles.css`, you save the file into a folder called `app` in the very root of your harddrive. Have you looked there? Try changing the path to a relative path.

Comment: After playing around with the path, I finally got the CSS to show up using:

new ExtractTextPlugin('./styles.css')

I still can't find the compiled css file, but I'll take what I can get, at this point.